# General efficiency questions regarding MySQL tables setup

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have couple questions regarding the best way to set up tables in MySQL DB.

1. Say I have multiple categories on a website; and I have multiple tables for those categories in the DB. However, for all the posts that use those categories, is it better to create only one table that holds all post records or separate them by the relevant category?
2. Same as above but for the user comments. Stick with one table or use multiple tables?

Answer (score 0):

1) I would keep all the posts in one table- if they are separate you'd have to do joins anytime you wanted to query posts across multiple categories.

2) Same idea, you want all your comments to be in one location, regardless of category.

Comment: Excellent. That's how I have it setup.

Answer (score 0):

Have a table for posts. another table for categories and a table that contains the relationship between them consisting post_id and category_id. This type of relationship is called many-many read more [here](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php)